# How to preinizialize Data into Tanstack Query Cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tanstackreact-query

This simple Hook

```
const routing = usePersistReadOnly("routing");
console.log("App.js:103: routing", routing);

---

const queryFn = ({ queryKey: [key, token] }) =>
  Persist.getItem(key, token) ?? null;

export const usePersistReadOnly = (key) => {
  const token = null;
  const queryResult = useQuery({
    queryKey: [key, token],
    queryFn,
  });

  return queryResult.data;
};
```

misses the initial Data in the cache

```
const baked = { routing: [1, 2, 3] }
// Init Cache with baked data
Object.entries(baked).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  queryClient.setQueryData([key], (v) => v ?? value);
  Persist.setItem("routing", [1, 2, 3])
  //queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: [key], refetchType: 'none'}) // Mark as stale -> refetch on use
});
```

during the initial render.

What needs to be changed to make this happen?

minimal viable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-query-cache-initialization-sc8twh?file=/src/index.js

qc:12 log shows data being available right after initialization

Answer (score 0):

`queryKey: [key]` is **not** a super set of `queryKey: [key, token]` for Query.
While this is used to invalidate and filter related queries, is is not for data identity.